# SIGBRT when using custom cell for UItableView Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Not sure why I keep getting SIGBRT. I have been stuck on this simple error for FAR to long and its starting to get annoying. anyone got any idea how to fix this? Everything seems to be linked up but the program crashs when The table view attempts to load the cells. NOTE: i am not using that image view or grey label, this was just a copied and pasted cell from a previous project.

.xib for custom cell: The identifier is "customMessageCell"

[image]

Code that uses the custom cell:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell" , for: indexPath) as! CustomMessage;
    let gray = UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.94, blue:0.94, alpha:1.0)
    let red = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.22, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    if message.toId == user?.toId{
    cell.messageBackground.backgroundColor = red
        cell.messageBody.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    else{
        cell.messageBackground.backgroundColor = gray
    }

    cell.messageBody.text = message.text


    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**
here is exact error message: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT crashs at line 1 of app-delegate.

Comment: Whenever you post a question about an error, you must do two things: 1 - Include the complete and exact error message, 2 - point out the exact line of code causing the error. Please [edit] your question (don't post comments) to include this information.

Comment: you are using xib for custom UITableviewCell, you first have to register xib in viewDidLoad.

Comment: your cell is simple why don't you user prototype cell in storyboard itself? Any specific reason for xib?

Answer (score 0):

Assign CustomCell class to the uitableviewcell in the interface builder and assign the cell reusable identifier to that class. This can be the main reason for the crash as in your case the tableview is not able to resolve the uitableviewcell having reusable cell identifier "customMessageCell"